# Why does the Laplace's equation imply linearity?

Tags: linear-algebra, laplacian

In one of my textooks I found Laplace's equation listed as

$$\nabla^2f=0$$

together with the following quote: *Laplace’s equation is linear, and hence any number of particular solutions to [equation above] can be added together to obtain another solution*.

I am not entirely certain if I understood this part correctly, so I would appreciate it if you could check my understanding and correct me if I misunderstand something.

As far as I understand, the critical thing is not that $\nabla^2f$ is linear, but that $\nabla^2f=f''=0$ implies linearity of $f$ (all linear functions have zero second derivative). And linear functions can be added together (due to [additivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity)) to obtain another linear function. This isn't quite what the textbook wrote (but maybe what they meant), which is why I'd like to double-check my interpretation of it first.

Comment: You got it wrong indeed: the point is only that $\nabla^2$ is linear.

Comment: It is just saying that if $f,g$ are solutions then so is $sf+tg$ for scalars $s,t$.

Comment: To say that $\nabla^2$ is linear is to say that $$\nabla^2(af+bg)=a\nabla^2f+b\nabla^2g$$

Comment: Thank you for the comments. So what is the significance of the $0$ on the RHS, then? Isn't the same statement true for any linear operator? What makes $\nabla^2$ special?

Comment: Yes, the same statement is true for any linear operator.  There is nothing special about $\nabla^2$.  If $T$ is a linear operator, any linear combination of solutions of $Tf=0$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for two reasons:

1: $\nabla^2$ is a linear operator

2: The PDE is homogeneous

I'll state without proof that for scalar fields $\Phi$ and $\Psi$, and scalars $a$ and $b$,
$$\nabla^2(a\Phi + b\Psi)= a\nabla^2(\Phi)+b\nabla^2(\Psi)$$
Therefore, if $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are solutions of Laplace's equation, then $\nabla^2(\Phi + \Psi)=\nabla^2(\Phi) + \nabla^2(\Psi)=0+0=0$ thus $\Phi + \Psi$ is also a solution of Laplace's equation. Note that this does not work for Poisson's equation: say $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ satisfy a special case of Poisson's equation, say $\nabla^2(U)=C$. Then
$$\nabla^2(\Phi + \Psi) = \nabla^2(\Phi)+\nabla^2(\Psi) = C+C=2C \neq C$$
Thus $\Phi + \Psi$ is **not** a solution.